# Tehilim for an illness

Tags: tefilla, tehilim-psalms, choleh-sick

What are the Chapters of Tehilim (Psalms) said for an ill person and what is the source in seforim and the reason for these particular chapters being chosen?

Comment: I do not know the answer to this question, but the questioner should check out (if available) the [Artscroll sefer Tehillim](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/tehh.html), as it has many different commentaries on exactly this style of question, and many more like it.

Comment: He mentions a few I believe...http://videos.videopress.com/GeKhk8hy/bemizvot_tamim_tihye_fmt1.ogv

Comment: two day ago I was searching exactly same and found this site http://itim.org.il/?CategoryID=429 (interesting coincidence)

Answer (score 4):

http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1228223/jewish/Psalms-and-Jewish-Prayer-for-Healing.htm

> When praying for an individual who is ill, it is customary to recite
>   the following thirty-six chapters of Psalms: 20, 6, 9, 13, 16, 17, 18,
>   22, 23, 28, 30, 31, 32, 33, 37, 38, 39, 41, 49, 55, 56, 69, 86, 88,
>   89, 90, 91, 102, 103, 104, 107, 116, 118, 142, 143, and 148.
>
> After this, recite the stanzas from Psalm 119 that correspond to the
>   letters of the ill individual's Jewish name(s). (Psalm 119 is an
>   acrostic containing twenty-two stanzas, each stanza consisting of
>   eight verses that begin with the same letter from the Hebrew alphabet.
>   The first eight verses all start with the letter aleph, the next eight
>   begin with bet, the next eight with gimel, etc.) E.g., if the person's
>   name is Moshe (משה), recite the stanzas that begin with mem, shin, and
>   hey. If the person's name is Rachel (רחל), recite the stanzas that
>   begin with resh, chet and lamed.