# Source for Tehillim as remedies to specific problems

Tags: sources-mekorot, tehilim-psalms

I have this (rather low-quality) "mini-siddur" e-book that I found long time ago. Among other things, it has a page called "Directory of Tehillim", which is a table where each Tehillim is assigned a certain purpose, for example:

> - Tehillim 9 - for a sick child
> - Tehillim 24 - to be saved from floods
> - Tehillim 108 - for success (material)
> - Tehillim 114 - for someone who buys and sells

The book does not specify the source for this. Where might this come from?

Also, is there any opinion on using the Tehillim in the manner suggested by such lists, in general?

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/14547/tehilim-for-an-illness

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/66090/perek-of-tehilim-for-someone-elses-spiritual-growth

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/29628/tehillim-while-waiting-for-medical-test-results